# Find duplicates in database based on two records

Tags: mysql, sql, select, duplicates

I have a database with fields like the following:

```
id -- user id -- role id

1  --- 100 ----- 119
2  --- 100 ----- 119
3  --- 101 ----- 101
4  --- 102 ----- 250
5  --- 103 ----- 300
```

I'd like to be able to feed in a list of user ids, and have it return which role id's are duplicated. For example, for the sample above, it would print out something like the following:

```
100 --- 119 --- 2
```

I'd like a query to be able to delete these duplicates as well, after I run the select to see the results

Comment: Please include the SQL statements you tried and that didn't work

Comment: Do yo want to remove both duplicates or leave one of them?

Comment: Don't really believe this is deserving of a downvote, but whatever.

Comment: I want to remove all but the duplicates and leave just one, so for this example it would delete one of the 119's

Answer (score 0):

select user_id, role_id, count(*)
from user_roles
where user_id in ()
group by user_id, role_id having count(*) > 1;